# Linear optimization for functions

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier

I have the following linear optimization problem.
$$
\max \int_0^1 w(t) dt
$$
subject to
$$
\int_0^1 w(t) \, x_i(t) \, dt \geq 0, \quad i=1,\dots,n 
$$
and
$$
0 \leq w(t) \leq 1 \quad \text{for all} \quad t\in[0,1].
$$
Here, $x_1(t), \dots, x_n(t)$ are some given functions $x_i:[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$, and the optimization is over all measurable functions $w:[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ satisfying the constraints.

I would like to prove that there exists a maximiser $w^*(t)$ such that for every $t\in[0,1]$ either $w^*(t)=0$ or $w^*(t)=1$.

This is "obvious" from the intuition that optimal solution for the linear program should be on the "corner" of the feasibility set. However, in this example we have uncountably many variables ($w(t)$ for each $t\in[0,1]$) and uncountably many constraints. Can anyone suggest a good reference for study of such linear programs, and/or provide a direct solution for this problem?

Comment: I suspect that there even ma be an explicit solution which could be found using duality (apply LP duality just like everything is finite dimensional and write down the optimality system). There should be n dual variables for the equality constraints and two more multipliers which are functions (well. probably measures) for the two inequality constraints.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. I found a lot of links and lecture notes which solves such problems by "applying LP duality just like everything is finite dimensional and writing down the optimality system" but no theorem which rigorously justifies that I can really do this in infinite dimension. How can I check, for example, that there is no duality gap?

Comment: You may use some of the "Fenchel-Rockafellar duality theorems" which state conditions under which strong duality holds for convex optimization problems of the form $\min f(Ax)+g(x)$ in Banach spaces  with f and g convex and lsc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenchel%27s_duality_theorem for some version.

Comment: Thank you, but the constraint qualification conditions seem to require the existence of w*(t) for which all the constraints in the inequalities are strict, which is not necessary the case.

Comment: It depends on your setup! You need to choose space in which you work, i.e. a Banach space where the w comes from. Could be, for example C(0,1) (continuous functions of [0,1]) or L²(0,1) )(square integrable functions on [0,1]). Moreover, you have to choose how to phrase your problem in that context. If you choose A as a map from X to R^n mapping w to the vector that contains the elements <w,x_i>, f by f(w) = <1,w> if 0≤w≤1 (and ∞ otherwise) and g(z) = 0 if z≥0 and ∞ otherwise, you'll need (for condition 2 on the wiki page) that there is some w such that <w,x_i> > 0 for all i.